# git show-branch equivalent for Mercurial

Tags: git, mercurial

Is there an equivalent for `git show-branch --reflog="25" --list {branch-name}` in Mercurial? I.e. a way of showing all commits made to a specific branch regardless of whether they have been merged or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need:

`hg log --branch <branchname>`

See `hg help log` for more information

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You can use either

`hg log -r0:: -b BRANCHNAME`
`hg log -r'branch(BRANCHNAME)'`
`hg log -r'reverse(branch(BRANCHNAME))'`
The 2nd and 3rd method are more powerful.

Use -lN to limit it to N changesets

See also hg help revset how to create nice detailed expressions to limit and fine-tune your log output, e.g. all unmerged heads of a branch like `hg log -r'branch(BRANCHNAME) and not merge() and head()'`

Comment: Thanks for the in depth answer but I went with the shorter command provided by @Duikboot